# Postgres - Select rownumber without a table but data from a function

Tags: postgresql, split, recursive-query, window-functions, connect-by

I'm trying to get some result like this:

```
rownumber | value
    1     |   a
    2     |   b
    3     |   c
```

Without any tables I'm doing something like this:

```
WITH RECURSIVE t(rownumber, value) AS (
select 1, regexp_split_to_table('a, b, c', ',')
UNION ALL
SELECT rownumber+1, regexp_split_to_table('a, b, c',',') FROM t 
)
SELECT * FROM t limit (select count(*) from regexp_split_to_table('a, b, c', ','));
```

But the results are not as expected.

The reason I'm doing this is because the value 'a, b, c' should be some variable.

In Oracle the SQL looks like this:

```
SELECT value  FROM (
        SELECT ROWNUM AS rownumber, trim(REGEXP_SUBSTR('a, b, c','[^,]+', 1, LEVEL)) AS value
        FROM DUAL CONNECT BY trim(REGEXP_SUBSTR('a, b, c', '[^,]+', 1, LEVEL)) IS NOT NULL 
      )
```

and It works.

What am I doing wrong in Postgresql?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is happening because regexp_split_to_table returns a table and not a single value for each rownumber.

Maybe a different approach will work? For example, this gives me the output you were after:

```
SELECT  regexp_split_to_table('a,b,c', ',')   as value, 
        rank() over(order by regexp_split_to_table('a,b,c', ','))   as rownumber
```

EDIT: The above will reorder the results which may not be what you want. The following will preserve the ordering:

```
WITH T as
(
SELECT  regexp_split_to_table('d,a,b,c', ',')   as value
)

SELECT  row_number() over() as rownumber,
        value

FROM    t
```

Comment: Thank you, that worked for me! Just added an outter select because I needed to filter by the rownumber from the table t like `select value from ([your bottom query]) as table where rownumber = [my_number]`

Comment: No worries, mate. Glad you're all sorted =).